# PSQL update syntax - using circular references to tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is the PSQL command I'm trying to write:

```
UPDATE accounts
  SET account_type_id=subquery.id
  FROM (SELECT id
          FROM account_types
          WHERE mongo_id = accounts.mongo_account_type_id) AS subquery
  WHERE accounts.id = 1;
```

Yields this error message:

> ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "accounts"
>   LINE 1: ...OM (SELECT id FROM account_types WHERE mongo_id =
>   accounts.m...
>                                                                ^ HINT:  There is an entry for table "accounts", but it cannot be referenced
>   from this part of the query.

A short explanation of data structure - migrating from MongoDB to PSQL, I have moved all the records over into PSQL maintaining the old Mongo BSONs for referencing and re-stitching the records with foreign key relationships - my accounts table has columns as follows:

```
mongo_id                       | 521289ae1e0345000200000f
mongo_merchant_id              | 55e13f0afbab68982e000006
mongo_account_type_id          | 521289c41e03450002000011
mongo_admin_id                 | 518b762e89651a0389000013
```

And my account_types table has :

```
mongo_id          | 521289c41e03450002000011
mongo_merchant_id | 55e13f0afbab68982e000006
```

So I'm trying to set the account_type_id field of my ACCOUNTS table to the INTEGER value of the id field from the ACCOUNT_TYPES table using accounts.mongo_account_type_id == account_types.mongo_id as the reference.

Ultimately, accounts should have account_type_id = 1 (in this case - this particular case the record is id 1 for account_type)

In my query I'm just confused as to how to subquery using the accounts table as the 'variable' for mongo_account_type_id .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your intention, the query should look like this:

```
UPDATE accounts a
SET account_type_id = t.id 
FROM account_types t
WHERE t.mongo_id = a.mongo_account_type_id
AND a.id = 1;
```